# Service Fabric: DnsService gets removed automatically

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I recently created a new (certificate secured) service fabric test cluster in Azure. It took a while to get everything up and running but i got it working in the end.

However after connecting to the Service Fabric Explorer i noticed that the Fabric Dns Service had a warning about an unhealthy partition. I couldn't find any other issues and decided to reboot the virtual machines to see if the problem would persist.

After the restart finished the Dns Service was completely gone from my list of system services.

I found a related app insights message stating:

> Service Deleted: Service DnsService of ServiceType DnsServiceType deleted in Application fabric:/System ApplicationType __FabricSystem.

The Service Fabric Version i'm using is 6.1.456.9494 and the machines are running Windows 2016 with container support.

I already tried this twice and i'm always getting the same result ...

This didn't happen to me with the former version.

So ... is there a known way to re-add the Dns Service? Has anything like this occured to somebody else as well? How to fix this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to an automated Service Fabric upgrade that automatically removed the DnsService by accident. According to this BugTracker entry the issue has already been fixed: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/796

For the record: the solution was to re-add the DnsService to the clusters fabricSettings and wait for the settings to get redistributed. See the linked github issue for instructions to fix.